# Outlook mail restriction on current date

Tags: python, datetime, automation, outlook

I am doing automation on the manual work where I am reading the data from outlook mail using win32.

But I need to read mail restrict on the current date otherwise won't read the mail. If mail is not there on a current date then it will skip this part. Below are the codes that compare the received date and today but getting the error.

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = folder.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
CurrentDateTime = dt.datetime.now()
CurrentDateTime = CurrentDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] == '" + CurrentDateTime +"'")
print(messages)
for m in messages:
    if m.Subject.startswith('Daily SSC count to SD Team'):
        m1=m.Body
        print(m1)
        break;
```

Error:

```
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Restrict
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot parse condition. Error at "=".', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

*It should be only one **`=`** not two **`==`** try it[Items.Restrict method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) it should give you current date and time*

*Example*

```
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] = '" + CurrentDateTime +"'")
```

*But if your are trying to set the filter for 24 hours then start with today's date with time **`00:00`** then use **`>=`*** on `current_date = dt.date.today()`

*full example*

```
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt


def outlook_email(Inbox):
    current_date = dt.date.today()
    print(current_date)
    
    current_date = current_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    print(current_date)
    
    items = Inbox.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>='" + current_date + "'")
    print(items.Count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace(
        "MAPI"
    )

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    outlook_email(inbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `=` when working with date/time properties - the condition will never be satisfied even if the value (both date **and** time) matches that of an existing message because of round-off errors.

Always use a range (`<` and `>`), or (if you are dealing with the current date and assume there won't be any messages with a newer date), use `>=` as @0m3r suggested.